# How do you obtain the crontab schedule from a crontab line using the modulepython-crontab?

Tags: python-2.7, cron

I have the following cron file (cron.txt):

```
03 09,17 * * * script1
03 08 * * * script2
00 08,11,14,17 * * * script3
00 20 * * * script4
00 07 1 * * script6767
```

and i want to write a piece of code in Python 2.7 that will print:
your script "script1" will run at "03 09,17 * * *" (i will use croniter to translate from cron to human language).

Using the code bellow:

```
from crontab import CronTab

file_cron = CronTab(tabfile='cron.txt')
for linie in file_cron:
    comanda = linie.command
    print comanda
```

I print the script or command that will run in crontab just fine while i iterate through the crontab lines but how do i print the time?
Is there any built in method from CronTab that can help me do this? as i done above with **linie.command**?
I want something like:

```
variable = linie.get_the_damn_cron_time
print variable


output: 03 09,17 * * *
```

How do i do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The values are stored in a structure called 'slices' which you can convert to a string directly like this:

```
for job in cron:
  print unicode(job.slices)
```